# Can't get Mac to use correct version of sqlite3

Tags: macos, sqlite, homebrew

I know variations of this question have been asked before and I've tried the recommendation listed in the other postings. I'm trying to get sqlite 3.11 installed in El Capitan using brew.

I did...

```
$ brew install sqlite3
$ brew link --force sqlite3
```

The `--force` was necessary because I got an error without it indicating `Warning: sqlite is keg-only and must be linked with --force`. Also, I have `/usr/local/bin` at the front of my `PATH`. So everything seems like it is set up correctly. Now I do this...

```
~ $ which sqlite3
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3
~ $ sqlite3 --version
3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12 a611fa96c4a848614efe899130359c9f6fb889c3
~ $ /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24 3d862f207e3adc00f78066799ac5a8c282430a5f
~ $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin  35 Feb 16 19:12 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 -> ../Cellar/sqlite/3.11.0/bin/sqlite3
~ $ /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.11.0/bin/sqlite3 --version 
3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24 3d862f207e3adc00f78066799ac5a8c282430a5f
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here. It says it's using the correct sqlite3, but the version is wrong. When I look at the homebrew version of sqlite3 that is linked to the one in /usr/local/bin it has the correct version number. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here or suggestions on how to remedy the problem?

Comment: You haven't got an alias defined have you? Try running `alias | grep -i sql`

Comment: Unless you really want to use sqlite3 on your production server for some strange reason I would circumvent the problem by using Postgres (or some other RDBMS) straight off the bat. http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Comment: @MarkSetchell: No there's not an alias, `alias | grep -i sql` yields nothing.

Comment: You haven't got any functions defined have you? Try running `declare -f | grep sql`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems like anaconda was screwing with my paths. Once I uninstalled anaconda, everything is good.